# Angular JS <input type="time"> is not working on Mozilla

Tags: angularjs, mozilla

Please help i am trying to implement Angular JS  but it is not working on Mozilla

Check fiddle on Mozilla

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="HistoryCtrl">
    <input type="date" ng-model="startDate" />
    <input type="time" ng-model="startTime" />
    <input type="date" ng-model="endDate" />
    <input type="time" ng-model="endTime" />
    <button ng-click="updateForm()">Update</button>
    <pre>Start Date: {{ startDate }}
Start Time: {{ startTime }}
End Date: {{ endDate }}

function HistoryCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.result = {
        result: 'success',
        start: '2013-11-23 03:00:00',
        end: '2013-11-24 16:30:00',
        delta: 0.05681799352169
    };

    $scope.updateForm = function () {
        console.log('updating delta balance');
        $scope.updateTimespan($scope.result.start, $scope.result.end);
    };

    $scope.updateTimespan = function (start, end) {
        $scope.startDate = start.split(" ")[0];
        $scope.startTime = start.split(" ")[1];
        $scope.endDate = end.split(" ")[0];
        $scope.endTime = end.split(" ")[1];
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t3m6r/3/

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla doesn't support date, time, month and few more input types as of now.

Instead use any existing time picker.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately mozilla doesn't support date/time input types. You can check the browser supports from [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=time)